# Rewrite: Moon and Terra ending

Tags: rewrite

In the anime ending of Rewrite season 2 (Moon and Terra) did the girls summon Kotarou as their familiar knowing who he is/was? They were still childs when he was around them trying to save the earth. When he brought them to the moon, to the Kagari of season 1 did the girls remember their past lives or alternate routes? Can someone explain the ending to me, I'm not sure whether it was a good or bad ending. He completed his initial objective, but was that a good thing in order to fullfil his promise?

It are a lot questions but they are all related to the ending of season 2, hence why I didn't make several threads for this but just one. I am not really into novels or mange (yes it's weird I know) so I'd appreciate it if someone could explain the ending. Up to the point where he thought that he couldn't kill her but chose to go against his own instinct I could follow the storyline, but after that it all felt kinda rushed and I think those only watching the anime might've missed out on a lot important information.

Comment: I would argue that the ending is quite ambiguous in relation to most of the questions. Only thing that is sure is that Kotarou's actions ended conflict between Gaia and Guardian and gave future to humankind. Anything else is irrelevant.

Comment: It all depends on how you interpret everything that happens in the epilogue. You can interpret it literary, as Kotarou himself being summoned and walking on the moon. Or metaphorically, where Kotarou's essence is summoned and "walking on the moon" is taken as metaphor for his ability to travel in space.

Comment: That reminds me, wasn't ending the conflict between the Gaia and Guardian the sole reason he was send to earth after the simulations on the moon? If that were the case then this indeed is a good ending.

I'm not sure whether it is his essence though. Due to rewriting he burned through his lifeforce which him turned into a tree which basically just changed his body, meaning he still is/was alive but just required some source of lifeforce in order to gain a "human"  body again.

Comment: Also, there is difference between original Rewrite and Rewrite+. In the original he doesn't seem to remember anything. While in +, he remembers the girls.

Comment: In the beginning of + he didn't remember anything either, for all he knew he was just a hunter with some dangerous special powers which he came to understand during the war. Eventually he got in touch with the girls by "coincidence" and at the last episode he finally regained his memories about the girls. In the first season he started to remember a lot eventually. But that was mainly because season 1 were a bunch of simulations for the the actual thing, which was in season 2 ending the conflict so that Kagari could have some "memories to be fond of".

Comment: Both Rewrites kinda had the same start and same ending memory wise. It started with him not remembering anything. He was just barely aware of his gift while as the story progressed he was more aware of his situation as well as the girls involved and their roles as well as his, however this was for both Rewrites when the story reached nearly it's climax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the 2nd season closed off with a good ending. My reasons for it is that Koutarou had the same relationship with the key by the complete end, but they all seemed to be back to how they normally were, school clothes and all the other things. I don't know why but I got the feeling they gasped not just because the two kissed, but because they knew the two of them so it was even more of a surprise.

A bad ending in my eyes would have kept him dressed in his butler suit and not have the scene where they look to be casually chatting while walking on the path of light on their way to the moon.

Answer (score 0):

So the conclusion is that weather you watch or not season 1 both season have same story the only difference is that the season 1 end with negative ending and the season 2 end with positive ending so I recommend to watch directly season 2